# UIButton and UITextField don't respond as part of UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am new to swift, I have this code, it is the `UIViewController` for the `UITextField` and `UIButton`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ManualTagController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    let addTagButton = UIButton()
    let tagTextfield = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.layer.cornerRadius = self.view.frame.width/80

        self.addTagButton.setTitle("TAG", for: .normal)
        self.addTagButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255, green: 17.0/255, blue: 57.0/255, alpha: 0.75)
        self.addTagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addTag), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addTagButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.addTagButton.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(addTagButton)

        self.tagTextfield.placeholder = "# or 'hey siri'"
        self.tagTextfield.alpha = 1
        self.tagTextfield.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 52)
        self.tagTextfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        self.tagTextfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        self.tagTextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        self.tagTextfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        self.tagTextfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
        self.tagTextfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
        self.tagTextfield.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(tagTextfield)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.addTagButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: self.view.frame.height - 77.0, width: self.view.frame.width - 20.0, height:72.0)
        self.addTagButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.addTagButton.frame.width/80
        self.tagTextfield.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 5.0, width: self.view.frame.width - 20.0, height:72.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc private func addTag() {
        //Database service code here...
        print("in addTag .........")
        //This will go where service is done and it is successful
    }

    internal func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {    //delegate method
        //
    }

    internal func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  //delegate method
        return false
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }
}
```

In my main `UIViewController` - it gets loaded like this, on a button click. it gets loaded fine - I am just showing how I am doing the `layer` here, and how it is initialized:

```
@objc private func openManualTag() {
        let frameHeightAdjusted = self.view.frame.height - 5/8 * self.view.frame.height
        let manualTag = ManualTagController()
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        manualTag.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        manualTag.view.clipsToBounds = false
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 159)).cgPath
        manualTag.view.tag = 1
        manualTag.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frameHeightAdjusted, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 159.0)
        manualTag.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -frameHeightAdjusted - 159)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.addSubview(manualTag.view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                manualTag.view.transform = .identity
            })
        }
    }
```

The problem is neither the `UIButton` nor the `UITextField` will work...neither respond to tapping them in anyway. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Posting all of `ViewController`, my main view controller, just incase:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var center = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let tagButton = TagButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openManualTag), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.tagButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255, green: 17.0/255, blue: 57.0/255, alpha: 0.5)
        self.tagButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.tagButton.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.tagButton.bounds, cornerRadius: self.tagButton.frame.width/2).cgPath
        self.tagButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        self.tagButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.tagButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.tagButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.tagButton.clipsToBounds = false
        self.tagButton.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.tagButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        view.addSubview(self.tagButton);
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        //let tagButton = view.viewWithTag(0)
        self.tagButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2 - 36, y: self.view.frame.height - 0.2 * self.view.frame.height, width: 72.0, height: 72.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView
    }

    func addMarker(tag: String) {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.center.latitude, longitude: self.center.longitude)
        marker.title = tag
        //marker.snippet = //USERNAME
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            marker.map = self.view as? GMSMapView
        }
    }

    @objc private func openManualTag() {
        let frameHeightAdjusted = self.view.frame.height - 5/8 * self.view.frame.height
        let manualTag = ManualTagController()
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        manualTag.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        manualTag.view.clipsToBounds = false
        manualTag.view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 159)).cgPath
        manualTag.view.tag = 1
        manualTag.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frameHeightAdjusted, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 159.0)
        manualTag.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -frameHeightAdjusted - 159)

        let transparencyButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        transparencyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha:0.4);
        transparencyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissHelper(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.addChildViewController(manualTag)
            self.view.addSubview(manualTag.view)
            manualTag.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                manualTag.view.transform = .identity
            })

            self.view.insertSubview(transparencyButton, belowSubview: manualTag.view)
        }
    }

    @objc func dismissHelper(sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.view.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()
        sender.isHidden = true;
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error" + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation = locations.last
        self.center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

        let mapView = view as! GMSMapView
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.center.latitude, longitude: self.center.longitude, zoom: 14.0)
        }

        print("Latitude :- \(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("Longitude :-\(userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)")

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are both of theiir `isUserInteractionEnabled` properties set to true?

Comment: thanks but it didnt help

Comment: the screen responds to my taps outside of the view of manualtag when it is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add some other view controller's view to your current VC you **must** firstly add that view controller as a child to your current one. This way UIKit will provide all touches as well as other VC related events to the child view controller correctly:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.addChildViewController(manualTag)
    self.view.addSubview(manualTag.view)
    manualTag.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        manualTag.view.transform = .identity
    })
}
```

Also I don't recommend you to modify "view" property of a UIViewController. This may lead to different issues, such as non-responding of your UITextField or Autolayout crashes. Just add your map as a full-screen subview in the viewDidLoad method:

```
super.viewDidLoad()

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.frame = view.bounds
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

And don't forget to remove your overriding of loadView() method!

Comment: thanks! that solves the button on manualTag....but the UITextField still isnt responding

Comment: so the UITextField delegate methods are not being called, right?

Comment: is it possible for you to share the project? would be much easier to find the error

Comment: just random thought now - are you running it in stimulator? then the keyboard may not be shown there but you are still able to type by hardware keyboard on your laptop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160355/discussion-between-ewizard-and-ruslan-serebriakov).

Comment: thanks trying now, i was wondering about the loadView seemed weird but it is google's example for some reason